# How to create cpio archive with custom structure

Tags: linux, archive

I have cpio archive with one file - `/./folder1/file1`

My goal is to replace `file1` with another one.

I unpacked my cpio archive to folder `/test` and replaced `file1`.

My structure:

```
/test/folder1/file1
```

I created new archive with this command:

```
find ./test | cpio -o -F newArch
```

But in `newArch` my files is stored as `/folder1/file1`.

How can I get archive with structure `/./folder1/file1`

Comment: You do realise that `/./` and `/` are identical in meaning?

Comment: yes. But when I open old archive by 7zip in Windows 7zip shows me /./folder1/ When I open my new archive 7zip shows /folder1/

Answer (score 0):

cpio doesn't have any prefix commands and although I still think it is a moot exercise, you can try if it preserves the filenames it gets via standard input:

```
find ./test -printf "././%f\n"| cpio -o -F newArch
```

Adjust the prefix of the format string as necessary. I don't have 7zip to test how it interprets the paths.

Comment: This method won't work. I tried different combinations but no result achieved.